# Need help for CI and CD in Github Workflow for Firebase Web App using HUGO Framework

Tags: firebase, web, github, workflow, hugo

I'm using HUGO to build a website and connected it in **Forestry.io** for headless cms. Everything is in my GitHub repository.
I have this 2 files in workflows folder under **.github** folder: **deploy.yml** and **integrate.yml**
I always get this error:

```
13 Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
14 Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

------deploy.yml and integrate.yml files------
name: Firebase Continuous Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - uses: actions/setup-node@master
        with:
          node-version: 10.16.0
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
name: Node Continuous Integration

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  test_pull_request:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm test
      - run: npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

Double-check with the [`w9jds/firebase-action`](https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action) GitHub Action instructions:

- the `build` job is suppose to execute the `npm` commands, not the `deploy` job
- the `deploy` job is supposed to call Firebase (`w9jds/firebase-action@master`) with `paths` parameters

That is:

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout Repo
    uses: actions/checkout@master
  - name: Download Artifact
    uses: actions/download-artifact@master
    with:
      name: dist
      path: dist
```

Comment: I have use the example in [link](https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action)
but I'm getting an error

Run npm run build-prod
  npm run build-prod
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
npm ERR! missing script: build-prod
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2020-08-17T16_58_18_556Z-debug.log
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: @EDC You can edit your question to add those details, with a better presentation/readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: dist
          path: dist
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: dist
          path: dist
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```